# Randomizing a color with fixed lightness

Tags: colors, color-space, lab-color-space

I want to randomize a number of colors, all having the same lightness (but different purdy colors). Now there's a nice colorspace like `LAB` that allows you to do that, but it gets a bit tricky when converting back to RGB as not all colors that you can pick in `LAB` space can be represented in the normal `RGB`.

I've decided to take the following approach (poor pseudocode, never mind the ranges and exact values):

```
L = some fixed value
while r, g or b not in range 0.0 to 1.0:
    a = random value
    b = random value
    r, g, b = LABtoRGB(L, a, b)
```

Now this tends to require only 1 or 2 iterations for `L=50` (because `RGB` can represent a large fraction of colors for that lightness), but I don't like this solution.

Surely there's a better way? Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

The simplest although not most accurate way of doing that would be to randomly choose `R, G & B` such that `sqrt(R^2+G^2+B^2) == L` (probably by drawing `R` from a normal distribution with mean of `L*sqrt(3)/3`, and `G` from a distribution with a mean of `(L^2-R^2) / 2` (`B` is now `sqrt(L^2 - R^2 - G^2)`)